# how to do simon says button input

Tags: java, android

I am working on a **simon says** project, I have an array that has the colors that light up on the buttons and then I have an empty array which is supposed to have the buttons the user has pressed, the problem is I don’t really know how to get the user button input (which buttons the user pressed and in what order) I also have a condition that if the user pressed the wrong buttons than the game starts a new activity, the problem is that now doesn't work and before I tweaked the code it did it almost instantly work unless I guessed the color which was about to light up here is my code, please help.

```
package com.gabie212.simonsays;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import static android.os.SystemClock.sleep;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int i = 0;
    private Thread t = new Thread();
    private Button greenButton;
    private Button redButton;
    private Button blueButton;
    private Button yellowButton;
    private Button startButton;

    private ArrayList<Integer> randomColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> userColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private GameManger gm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gm =  new GameManger(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
        redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
        blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        yellowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        redButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        blueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        yellowButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int num;
        num = gm.getColor(4);
        randomColors.add(num);
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();  
        //TODO if the start button is pressed multiple times simultaneously it starts the lightup loop multiple times simultaneously
        if (v.getId() == startButton.getId()) {
            for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) //light up loop
            {
                switch (randomColors.get(i)) {
                    case 1:
                      greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                            }
                        }, 2000);    
                        break;
                    case 2:                            redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                            }
                        }, 2000);    
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluelightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                            }
                        }, 2000);    
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                            }
                        }, 2000);    
                        break;
                }
            }

            for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
            {    
                if(v.getId()==greenButton.getId())
                {
                    userColors.add(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(v.getId()==redButton.getId()){
                        userColors.add(2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(v.getId()==blueButton.getId())
                        {
                            userColors.add(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            userColors.add(4);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            if(randomColors.size()!=userColors.size()) {
                for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) {
                    if (randomColors.get(i) != userColors.get(i)) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                }
            }
            userColors.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so to clarify, the first switch case is how the colors light up and it randomizes a number and lights up the according number.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int num;
    num = gm.getColor(4);
    randomColors.add(num);
    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();

    //TODO if the start button is pressed multiple times simultaneously it starts the lightup loop multiple times simultaneously
    if (v.getId() == startButton.getId()) {
        for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) //light up loop
        {
            switch (randomColors.get(i)) {
                case 1:                        greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluelightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowlightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Then there is the are, the if, and the loop that are supposed to get the buttons that the user has inputted.

```
for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
        {
            if(v.getId()==greenButton.getId())
            {
                userColors.add(1);
            }
            else
            {
                if(v.getId()==redButton.getId()){
                    userColors.add(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(v.getId()==blueButton.getId())
                    {
                        userColors.add(3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userColors.add(4);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and then finally the part that checks if the buttons are the right buttons and if not it sends the user to a different activity that says that the game is over

```
if(randomColors.size()!=userColors.size()) {
            for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) {
                if (randomColors.get(i) != userColors.get(i)) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

        }
        userColors.clear();
    }
}
```

how do I can make my program get the input of the buttons in a way that would work?

Comment: This does not look like a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve